# Snowflake - collaborating as a team - recommendations wanted

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a team of 20-30 analysts working globally. We've just migrated to Snowflake. I'm looking for recommendations on an approach to use a query library (repository) and share as a group. I am currently going down the DataGrip or PopSQL path, but I wondered if anyone had a workable solution in Snowflake already.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you looked at the new Snowflake UI (Snowsight)?  You can share worksheets and dashboards with others on the team.

Comment: Stack Overflow usually prefers programming questions, rather than discussions and recommendations. https://reddit.com/r/snowflake is a good alternative for discussions

Answer (score 0):

You may use the new UI, Snowsight and take advantage of the sharing of worksheets and dashboards as described in the document below:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-share.html

To launch the new UI, log in to your Snowflake account (classic UI) on the top right corner of the page, there is an icon "Snowsight". Click on that icon, you will be redirected to the new UI. More on the new UI here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-gs.html